# Sharepoint services image hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint, hyperlink, wss-3.0

I am using Sharepoint service to create a webpage. I have an image - the logo on the top-right of the homepage - and am wanting to put a hyperlink so when it is pressed it takes you to another site. How would I do that please?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
Next time I'll read the question more carefully. I mixed up right with left and thought he want to change the logo in the top left next to the site's title.

The question is, should the link point always to the same target and should the logo be always the same one or will the link target and logo differ from site to site?

If it should be always the same logo then editing the master page would be the easiest solution.

For different link targets and logos you have to plan a little bit more. First you'll need a place where you could store the link target. I think the SPWeb's PropertyBag would be a good place therefore. Furthermore you need a place to store the you logo. In this case a library on the new site will do the job.

Finally I would implement a control that creates the HTML to display the logo with a link. The control retrieves the logo (logo's url) from the library and the link target form the actual site's PropertyBag. So the last step would be to replace the old logo control with your new one.

Comment: that was sorted, now i have a bug. im running the site on a VM with windows server on, even tho that it is running, other people cannot log into the site, i can when i log in as them on my own laptop, how do i fix this. (this is only a development machine but i need to show teachers at my school before i can implement it. thanks

Comment: i know your thinking i should show them off my laptop but if it dont work in development stage, it might not work in the real world

Comment: I think you have to open a new question for your new problem as it is not related to the actual question.